# Изменить уведомление, что скрыты вопросы с игнорируемыми метками

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Настроил в профиле игнорируемые метки и отметил, чтобы вопросы с ними скрывались. Теперь в конце списка вопросов вижу предупреждение со ссылкой на настройки:

[image: Скрыть вопросы на основании параметров игнорируемых меток для меток]

Во-первых, в первом слове опечатка. Нужно `СкрытЫ` вместо `СкрытЬ`.

Во-вторых, хочется улучшить [фразу целиком](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265938):

```
Скрыть вопросы на основании [параметров игнорируемых меток]($url$) для меток:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, и без лишних слов понятно, что по ссылке окажется список игнорируемых меток и связанные с ними параметры. Предлагаю вариант:

```
Скрыты вопросы с [игнорируемыми метками]($url$):
```

[image: Настройка меток]

Comment: Ссылка всё-таки ведёт не на игнорируемые метки, а на страницу настроек.

Comment: @NickVolynkin По ссылки открывается страница "Параметры", в конце которой идёт блок про метки: список избранных, список игнорируемых и нужно ли их скрывать. Т.е. - всё в одном месте, которое и открывается по ссылке. Добавил скриншот к своему ответу.

Comment: Во всяком случае там не только игнорируемые метки.  Можно назвать ссылку "параметры".

Comment: @NickVolynkin Чем это слово поможет человеку? Цель сообщения - обратить внимание человека, что он видит не всё, а только вопросы по меткам, которые выбрал. Текст сообщает. Картинки с метками - напоминают, что именно выбирал. Добавляем ссылку на слова "игнорируемые метки", чтобы: 1) напомнить, что метки можно настраивать и 2) показать короткий путь к настройкам. Слова "настроить" или "параметры" плохи трижды: 1) удлиняют текст, а это всего лишь рабочая ссылка, она должна быть как можно короче; 2) вклиниваются между словом "метки" и перечислением меток; 3) отвлекают от меток на параметры вообще.

Comment: Помню, у Лебедева в Ководстве была статья про именование ссылок. Пойду перечитаю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin § 83. [Секреты хорошего гипертекста](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/83/)

Answer (score 1):

Хотелось бы обозначить, что ссылка ведёт на страницу настроек. Какой-нибудь из этих вариантов:

```
Скрыты вопросы с игнорируемыми метками ([настроить]($url$)): 
Скрыты вопросы с игнорируемыми метками ([параметры]($url$)):
```

Выглядеть будет так (ссылка рабочая).

---

Скрыты вопросы с игнорируемыми метками ([настроить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current)):
[a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a), [b](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/b), [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

---

Скрыты вопросы с игнорируемыми метками ([параметры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current)):
[a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a), [b](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/b), [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

Comment: Предлагаю вместо этого попросить разработчиков добавить  [#ignored-wrapper](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#ignored-wrapper) или [#ignoredTags](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#ignoredTags) к ссылке, которую они сюда подставляют. (Можно и самим добавить этот хвост к переводу, но лучше совершенствовать систему в целом.)

Comment: "изменить настройки" -> "настроить" А вообще, действительно лучше добавить id.

Comment: Ещё одно соображение: сообщение об игнорируемых метках появляется только после того, как человек **сам** найдёт страницу с параметрами,  в параметрах отыщет раздел про метки, составит их список и нажмёт галочку "скрывать". Думаю, после этого его уже не надо так уж водить за ручку и предупреждать, что по ссылке будет не просто страница про метки, а страница параметров, на которой метки тоже настраиваются.

Comment: @Qwertiy переформулировку принял, а вот про id неясно, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: Думаю, речь идёт об id блока с настройками меток, который можно добавить к ссылке, чтобы страница сама прокручивалась к настройке меток. Этот id можно подсмотреть, открыв HTML-код страницы. Я уже добавил два варианта ссылок в первом комментарии к этому ответу.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky а, тогда понятно.

Comment: @NickVolynki, да.